# Android .SF file

Tags: java, android-manifest

I want to know what are the differences between a MANIFEST.MF file and a .SF file in the Android context.

As I can see, MANIFEST.MF file has the sha1 digest of each source file of an Android .apk.

However .SF also lists all sources and computes a SHA1 digest. On what is this digest value computed??

Any ideas?

Also how to view a .RSA(Signature block file)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The digests in the .SF file are computed by hashing the 3 lines of the corresponding entry in the .MF file.  The .RSA (or .DSA) file contains a signature of the .SF file created from the signing private key, along with the public certificate chain of the signing key.  The .RSA (or .DSA) file is in a binary (i.e. non-human readable) format that can be programmatically parsed with effort.  More information can be found at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html

Comment: The link is dead.